# How to pass JS variable to Modal route

Tags: javascript, laravel, bootstrap-modal

im trying to update data from modal so that i want pass id to my form route how can i do here

```
$("body").on("click",".edit-item",function(){
        var id = $(this).parent("td").data('id');
        console.log(id);
        var description = $(this).parent("td").prev("td").prev("td").text();
        var log_time = $(this).parent("td").prev("td").text();
        var url  = '{{url('calls/'.$call->id.'/sub_calls/'.$subCall->id.'logs')}}}'
        $("#edit-item").find("input[name='description']").val(description);
        $("#edit-item").find("textarea[name='log_time']").val(log_time);
        $("#edit-item").find("form").attr("action",url + '/' + id);
    });
```

i want pass this **var id** to modal route here next to **$subcall->id**

```
{!! Form::model(['route' => ['calls.sub_calls.logs.update',$call->id,$subCall->id],'class'=>'form-horizontal','role'=>'form']) !!}
```

my route

```
Route::model('logs','App\Models\SubCalls\SubPortLog');
Route::resource('calls.sub_calls.logs','SubPortLogController');
```

Comment: Show your routing for this action

Comment: chek my route @FilipKoblański

Comment: Generate the url to the route but replace the `id` parameter with something like `~id`. Store it in a js variable: `var urlFormat={{ url(/* params */) }};`. Then you can just use `urlFormat.replace('~id', id)` to generate the link and replace the form's action with it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass it in the routing file (it's wher you define routes) like this:

```
Route::post('calls/sub_calls/logs/{id}/update/{subId?}', ['uses' => 'SomeController@upddate']);
```

if you have derfined this route with `Route::resource` method then you should put my example from above just in front of this declaration like this:

```
Route::post('calls/sub_calls/logs/{id}/update/{subId?}', ['uses' => 'SomeController@upddate']);
Route::resource('calls/sub_calls/logs','SubPortLogController');
```

And then in your controller metyhod do it like this:

```
public function update($id, $subId = null)
```

**UPDATE:**

Try this:

Define form with a shortcode as a secound parameter i.e. `:subId`:

```
{!! Form::model(['route' => ['calls.sub_calls.logs.update',$call->id, ':subCallId'],'class'=>'form-horizontal','role'=>'form']) !!}
```

and then just replace it with the value that you want:

```
$("body").on("click",".edit-item",function() {
    var id = $(this).parent("td").data('id'),
        action = $('form').prop('action').replace();

    $('form').prop('action', action);
    (...)
}
```

Comment: routing is not a problem i have this requiement plz chek this [LINK](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/update-data-ajax-modal-laravel)

Comment: if i pass this id `var id = $(this).parent("td").data('id');` into form action this should work but how do i pass?

Comment: please can you chek ths https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/update-data-ajax-modal-laravel

Comment: Yes you can make `$.ajax()` call passing `action = $('form').prop('action').replace();` url to it insted of `$('form').prop('action', action);`, how can I helps you with it?

Comment: @please chek this [LINK1](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByoLPyyQ3jAjaVBsVXNpMEp2Qk0) [Link2](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/update-data-ajax-modal-laravel) help me on this